O meu switch para mudar para o mudar tema escuro no Android Studio
Criei um Switch para mudar o tema do app do modo claro para escuro, porém o app acaba quebrando...
no Fragment layout:
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/btnDarkMode"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Modo Escuro"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:checked="false"
        tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" />

Na MainActivity:
val btnDarkMode = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.btnDarkMode)

        btnDarkMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked){
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            }else{
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
        }

